Setup Entra/Azure AD Connect with PowerShell for GCP Managed AD
I deployed AD Domain Controller using GCP Managed Microsoft AD service. I also deployed ADFS (following the GCP's docs).
Now, I want to setup AD/Entra connect to sync my AD with my MS365 Entra ID (Azure AD). Problem is, I don't have Domain Admins rights in a Managed Microsoft AD domain. So, when I try to setup AD Connect with ADFS I get the error
User [domain]\setupadmin is not a member of the Domain Admins group of [domain]

This happens on both setupadmin (the default admin user provided when creating a domain in GCP) and the ADFS admin created in the ADFS guide.
So, how can I setup AD connect with this limitation? Can I setup Connect using PowerShell and manipulate the user just like in the ADFS guide?
